# File Download from File Manager

Tags: file-uploads, multi-site-manager, file-manager

I need to download all the files I have uploaded to my site.  It will take forever for them to download through the file manager.  What is the best way for me to get them downloaded and how?

Answer (score 0):

EE3+4 have an option to export all files in the file manager. If you run into memory issues you may want to just use the alternative below.

For EE2 it might work best to use FTP to archive the folders into a zip file.